# Mrs Reed safe combination

Tags: combinatorics

Mrs Reed forgets the number combination to her safe. The combination has $4$ numbers each is a $1$ digit number. The $4$ digits add up to $10$ and there are no zeros. How many times does Mrs Reed have to try to open her safe?

My attempt: ${9 \choose 3} = 84$ but the answer is $80$.

Comment: 10 identical beads have 9 spaces between them. Choose any 3 of them to be boundaries.

Comment: Yes it does I think

Comment: Answer: 1.  Mrs. Reed texts Mr. Reed, who remembers the combination.  A malicious attacker would only need to try 84 combinations to open her safe with that information.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the digits are allowed to be repeated:  A rewording of the question is how many integer solutions exist for the constraints: $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 10$, $9\geq x_1\geq 1$, $9\geq x_2\geq 1$, $9\geq x_3\geq 1$, $9\geq x_4\geq 1$.  (the fact they are bounded above by 9 is given by the fact that they are 1 digit numbers.)

By a change of variables setting $8 = 9-1\geq x_i-1 = y_i \geq 0$, you see that $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 6$.  Noting that there is no way to contradict the inequality on the left, there will be no "bad" cases.

By stars and bars method, it would be $\binom{6+4-1}{4-1}$ number of solutions, which is indeed $\binom{9}{3} = 84$.  My answer agrees with yours.

Comment: Thanks now I am sure the answer is wrong.

Comment: The answer writer may have erroneously thought to subtract certain improper cases, such as the answer $(10,0,0,0)$ or $(0,10,0,0)$, since it was given that the numbers had to be 1 digit, however since there is no way to have chosen a $10$ while at the same time avoiding zeroes, we already avoided those cases from the start by changing variables to $y$.  That could explain the difference of 4 from the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since all combinations for this type of lock have numbers that add up to $10$, the manufacturer supplies a paper with ten strokes printed on it to secretly record the actual combination, like so `| | | | | | | | | |`. Now instead of writing the code explicitly (which is too obvious to decipher if the paper should be lost), you instead put in three commas to record so 2152 would be recorded as `| |,|,| | | | |,| |`. Indeed that can be done in $\binom93=84$ ways. Now if only Mrs. Reed could find that piece of paper...

Comment: That's a nice visual way to think about it while avoiding having to change variables.  It should be mentioned I think that in writing the code, you are not allowed to write a comma to the left of the leftmost bar, nor to the right of the rightmost bar, and cannot write more than one comma in the same space, which guarantees that there are no zeroes in the combination.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

Let the required combination be $d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4$.

Then $d_1$ can be any of the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$, and it can be one of only these numbers. So we have to consider seven cases.

Case 1. $d_1 = 7$: 
Then $d_2 = d_3 =d_4 =1$. So there's just one possibility.

Case 2. $d_1 = 6$: 
Then we can give $d_2$, $d_3$, $d_4$ the following sequences of values. $2$, $1$, $1$: $1$, $2$, $1$: and $1$, $1$, $2$. Thus, there are three possibilities.

Case 3. $d_1 = 5$. 
Then we can have these sequences. $3, 1, 1$; $1, 3, 1$; $1, 1, 3$; $2, 2, 1$; $2, 1, 2$; and $1, 2, 2$. Thus there are six possibilies.

Case $d_1 = 4$. 
Then we have available the following sequences. $4, 1, 1$; $1, 4, 1$; $1, 1, 4$; $3, 2, 1$; $3, 1, 2$; $2, 3, 1$; $2, 1, 3$; $1, 2, 3$; $1, 3, 2$. Thus there are nine possibilites.

Now continue in this way. At the end, add up the number of possibilities corresponding to each of the seven cases.

Comment: Brute force can often work, however in the case that it was a 10 number lock with each part of the combination being a 1,2 or 3 digit number.  There would be $10^{1000}$ possible ways to arrange them with no constraints, and could take forever to solve, even by a computer.  It is much cleaner to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29